# Get item from json object with key:value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like know if we can get an item from json by providing a key value pair.

For eg. I have a json object like below

```
[
{id: "864", text: "[145-028] ", name: "145028", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "593", text: "[111-111] ", name: "111111", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "616", text: "[330-00D] ", name: "33000D", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "595", text: "[124-964] ", name: "124964", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "597", text: "[476-978] ", name: "476978", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "131", text: "[142-222] ", name: "142222", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "132", text: "[149-603] ", name: "149603", type: null, description: ""},
{id: "603", text: "[778-498] ", name: "778498", type: null, description: ""}
]
```

How can I get a single item by id `864`, so that I can get the name, type and description for the particular item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: can you please clarify if the object has keys like 0,1,2 or you just copied from console?

Comment: What's a JSON object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `filter`. It will return another array. Use `index` to get the object and retrieve name from it

```js
let data = [{
    id: "864",
    text: "[145-028] ",
    name: "145028",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "593",
    text: "[111-111] ",
    name: "111111",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "616",
    text: "[330-00D] ",
    name: "33000D",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "595",
    text: "[124-964] ",
    name: "124964",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "597",
    text: "[476-978] ",
    name: "476978",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "131",
    text: "[142-222] ",
    name: "142222",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "132",
    text: "[149-603] ",
    name: "149603",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "603",
    text: "[778-498] ",
    name: "778498",
    type: null,
    description: ""

  }
];

function getval(id) {

  let obj = data.filter(item => item.id === id);
  return obj[0].name;
}

console.log(getval('864'))
```

Alternatively you can also use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Unlike `filter` it will return the first object where the `id` matches.

```js
let data = [{
    id: "864",
    text: "[145-028] ",
    name: "145028",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "593",
    text: "[111-111] ",
    name: "111111",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "616",
    text: "[330-00D] ",
    name: "33000D",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "595",
    text: "[124-964] ",
    name: "124964",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "597",
    text: "[476-978] ",
    name: "476978",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "131",
    text: "[142-222] ",
    name: "142222",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "132",
    text: "[149-603] ",
    name: "149603",
    type: null,
    description: ""
  },
  {
    id: "603",
    text: "[778-498] ",
    name: "778498",
    type: null,
    description: ""

  }
];

function getvalUsingFind(id) {

  return data.find(item => item.id === id).name;
}

console.log(getvalUsingFind('864'))
```

Comment: your solution is based on a js object different from the question

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, can you please suggest me which one would you prefer (id value will be unique)

Comment: @MisterJojo It was my mistake, actually my object is rendered through ajax and it contains 10k+ items. So I just copied data console.

Comment: @Munawir if `id` is unique, use `find`. Also not you need polyfill for ie browser

Comment: @Munawir in the future be more specific, you made me waste my time

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```js
const MyData = [{ 0: {id: "864", text: "[145-028] ", name: "145028", type: null, description: ""}
                , 1: {id: "593", text: "[111-111] ", name: "111111", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 2: {id: "616", text: "[330-00D] ", name: "33000D", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 3: {id: "595", text: "[124-964] ", name: "124964", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 4: {id: "597", text: "[476-978] ", name: "476978", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 5: {id: "131", text: "[142-222] ", name: "142222", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 6: {id: "132", text: "[149-603] ", name: "149603", type: null, description: ""} 
                , 7: {id: "603", text: "[778-498] ", name: "778498", type: null, description: ""} 
                }];

function MyDataGetVal(x_ID) {
  return Object.values(MyData[0]).find(E=>E.id===x_ID )|| null;
}


let E_864 = MyDataGetVal('864')
  , E_132 = MyDataGetVal('132')
  , E_XXX = MyDataGetVal('XXX')
;

console.log ('E_864 = ',  JSON.stringify(E_864))

console.log ('E_132 = ',  JSON.stringify(E_132))

console.log ('E_XXX = ',  JSON.stringify(E_XXX))
```

Comment: This only works when the element you want to find is in `MyData[0][0]`. Additionally, it breaks when no element was found.